# Correct Grammar on Moderator Tools Privilege Page

Tags: bug, status-completed, 10k-tools, wording

The [Moderator Tools Privilege description page](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools) jumps perspectives.  It reads:

> **Can I see all flags?**
>
> No. If you pick the flag → it needs ♦ moderator attention → other
>   option, your flag will be treated with the highest confidentiality and
>   will only be visible to community moderators and Stack Exchange
>   employees.
>
> In addition, flagged comments and spam/offensive flag counts are not
>   visible to you.

In other words, "Can *I* see all the flags?" is from the perspective of someone with the moderator tools privilege.  The next paragraph begins, "If *you* pick the flag..." (instead of "If someone picks the flag.")  We've now switched to the perspective of the person being moderated.  Then the last line, "are not visible to you" switches back to the privilege-holder perspective.  Instead, how about the following:

> **Can I see all flags?**
>
> No. If someone picks the flag → it needs ♦ moderator attention → other
>   option, the flag will be treated with the highest confidentiality and
>   will only be visible to community moderators and Stack Exchange
>   employees.
>
> In addition, this privilege does not reveal flagged comments and spam/offensive flag counts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Fixed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/66326/22). Also fixed the grammar of "In addition, flagged comments and spam/offensive flag are not visible to you."

This may take some time to update, looks like SO is still stuck on [revision 19](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/66326/19) (since the word "counts" was removed in [revision 20](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/66326/20))